# Campo decimal apresenta um .0 na tela

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um campo CPF que é decimal(11). Bem, quando eu mostro na grid o CPF ele fica assim: 12345678911.0, como eu posso remover o .0?

Minha ViewModel

```
public class FuncionarioViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public String nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data de Nascimento do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "formato de data invalido")]
        public DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "CPF do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "CPF")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Formato inválido")]
        public String cpf { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nome da Cidade")]
        public String NomeCidade { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cidade do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
        public virtual int cidade { get; set; }
    }
```

Minha tela de getfuncionarios

```
@model IEnumerable<TreinamentoCrud.FuncViewModel.FuncionarioViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "IndexVM";
}

<h2>Lista de Funcionários</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Novo Funcionário", "CreateVM")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dataNascimento)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cpf)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeCidade)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cidade)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dataNascimento)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cpf)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeCidade)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cidade)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("EditVM", "EditVM", new { id=item.id }) |
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |*@
            @Html.ActionLink("DeleteVM", "DeleteVM", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Método para pegar a lista de funcionarios

```
public async Task<List<FuncionarioViewModel>> GetFuncionariosVM()
        {
            string url = $"http://localhost:56137/api/GetFuncionario";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var _funcionario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FuncionarioViewModel>>(response);   


            return _funcionario;
        }
```

Comment: Já tentou converter pra inteiro? E porque está lidando com cpf como decimal? Geralmente utiliza string ou inteiro para representação do mesmo.

Comment: O requisito dizia numérico de 11, mas acho que o 11 era apenas o máximo. Acho que foi pegadinha mesmo

Comment: @pnet não sei se perguntei isso antes, você já pensou em fazer um curso para entender como as coisas funcionam?

Comment: @pnet O CPF é um documento padrão usado no brasil ele sempre terá 11 algarismos e é feito de uma forma na qual os 9 primeiros dígitos são o número em si e os 2 últimos são dígitos verificadores, por isso geralmente ele é tratado como texto, pois existe uma fórmula pra verificar se o cpf é válido ou não. Geralmente especifica-se como campo numérico porquê o cpf só tem números, mas a nível de programação e banco de dados pode ser texto.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista, concordo plenamente com você, mas se eu trocar por conta própria, eu ter problemas. O requisito diz, numérico de 11 e o único campo numérico que conheço que aceita length é o decimal. Falei com um colega e ele me disse para fazer conforme o requisito.

Comment: @pnet Já aviso que você terá problemas com esse método. Tipos numéricos como int, long, float e etc, ignoram o 0(zero) à esquerda e essa informação será perdida tanto no banco quando no seu código. Sendo assim todos os cpfs que começam com zero não irá funcionar. E sim, existe cpf que começa com 0.

Comment: Então, nesse caso eu uso um padleft(11) para mostrar no grid e no banco também

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa convert para long. Pois se converter pra inteiro ele pode estourar o limite.

> Valor máximo para uma variável do tipo int.   2147483647

```
decimal cpf = 79399965412; // vem do banco tipo decimal
long novoCpf = (long)cpf ; // transforma pra long
```

Outra opção é trabalhar com ele no formato Varchar no banco.